# how to cancel (not terminate) boost thread?

Tags: multithreading, boost

I like C# `CancellationTokenSource` which allows me to terminate the `Task` as shown in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396.aspx%5C).

What would be the similar algorithm of canceling `boost::thread`? I don't want to "kill" or "terminate" the thread. Instead i want to "request" the task to finish. Then i need to wait until the task is finished.

Comment: If your on windows using a while loop with a windows event that can be set externally is quite effective.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [boost thread interruption](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.tutorial.interruption)

> A running thread can be interrupted by invoking the interrupt() member
>   function of the corresponding **boost::thread** object. When the
>   interrupted thread next executes one of the specified interruption
>   points (or if it is currently blocked whilst executing one) with
>   interruption enabled, then a boost::thread_interrupted exception will
>   be thrown in the interrupted thread. If not caught, this will cause
>   the execution of the interrupted thread to terminate. As with any
>   other exception, the stack will be unwound, and destructors for
>   objects of automatic storage duration will be executed.